# Phabricator : [Access Denied: Restricted Project] (Can View) You do not have permission to view this object

Tags: php, phabricator

I'm trying to debug Phabricator Conduit API, spesifically in maniphest.search API. Where can i find this response in the Phabricator ?

```
[Access Denied: Restricted Project] (Can View) You do not have permission to view this object. // Members of a particular project can take this action. (You can not see this object, so the name of this project is restricted.) Members of a project can always view it.
```

I'm guessing there's a problem with the business logic according policy permission.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is validate that the conduit token you are using to make the API request belongs to a user that has access to this project.

Can you confirm that the correct token is being sent in your request?

Additional Things to check

- Project Membership
- The Space the project is in
- The "Visible To" and "Editable By" sections under "Manage Project->Edit Details"